# Piecewise representation of $\int x^a \,dx$

Tags: integration, notation, singularity

I was reading about antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ and they represented it as a piecewise function to include the negatives.

Like this:
$$  F(x) =
\begin{cases}
\ln (-x) + C_1, & x<0 \\
\ln (x) + C_2, &x>0 
\end{cases}
$$

My question is about the antiderivative of $x^a$ and if you could represent it by including the peices from the antiderivative of $1/x$ along with the integration rule. Is this a correct way of represeting the $ \int x^a \,dx$ ?

$$  \int x^a \,dx =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1} + C_1,  & a \neq -1 \\
\ln (-x) + C_2, & a = -1 \wedge (x<0) \\
\ln (x) + C_3, & a = -1 \wedge (x>0)  
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: So, so you claim $x^\pi$ makes sense for $x<0$?  And why should the constant in $\int x^{-2}\,dx$ be the same on both sides of $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct, I only have two remarks:

- You should define $C_j$. (In your case probably real.)
- You can simply write for $a=1$, $\log\lvert x\rvert+C$, where $C$  might take different values for positive or negative $x$.

Comment: Although I agree with your answer, there is a misleading component: In $\log|x| + C$, the "$C$" can be different for the left half and the right half of the $x$ number line.  It is probably a good idea to capture that there is no reason the vertical shift for $x < 0$ must agree with the vertical shift for $x > 0$.

Comment: That is correct but I'm not implying that. Nonetheless your comment could be helpful for the OP.

Comment: The usual method for producing an antiderivative from the general antiderivative is to specialize the constant of integration to a number.  Here, we have to use a different procedure: specialize the constant of integration to one number for $x < 0$ and one number for $x > 0$, which two numbers may be the same.  The collection of antiderivatives has two parameters, not one, but the notation you use is not compatible with this difference.

Comment: <chuckle>  Okay...  But now this notation needs explanation about *where* each $C_i$ applies.